# In QFT is there a single Hilbert space or a fiber bundle of Hilbert spaces?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, differential-geometry

In QFT, I understand that we have field operators $\hat \phi(\underline{x},t)$ acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Operators (e.g. creation/annihilation operators) can change the state in $\mathcal{H}$ so $\hat \phi(\underline{x},t)|\psi\rangle \to|\psi'\rangle$

What I don't understand is whether there is a copy of $\mathcal{H}$ at every point in spacetime - ie a fiber bundle so that $|\psi\rangle$ describes the state at $(\underline x,t)$ or whether there is one single $\mathcal{H}$ for the whole universe. In other words, is the field an infinite collection of operators, each acting on its own $\mathcal{H}$, or a single $\mathcal{H}$ that's acted on by an infinite collection of operators?

If (as I suspect) it's more like the latter, I'm confused about what this even means, mathematically. Does $\hat \phi(\underline{x},t)|\psi\rangle$ basically mean $\hat \phi(\underline{x_0},t_0)\hat \phi(\underline{x_1},t_1)\hat \phi(\underline{x_2},t_2)...|\psi\rangle$? And if it's something like that, what does that actually mean given that this isn't actually a countable infinity so we can't apply the operators sequentially like this? Or does it mean something completely different?

Comment: The operator field isn't a function of infinitely many variables, in $D$ spacetime dimensions the "function" $\phi(\vec x,t)$ is $\phi(x_1,x_2,...,x_{D-1},t)$ and gives you the operator at that point in spacetime.

Comment: Indeed - but there's then an operator at every one of those infinitely many points in spacetime

Comment: Each $\phi(x,t)$ is acting in the same Hilbert space, so you can think of them as an infinite set of operators labeled by points $(x,t)$. Caveat: this is not quite accurate, $\phi(x,t)$ is typically not a well-defined operator, one has to first smear it, e.g. form $\phi(f) = \int \phi(x,t) f(x,t) dx dt$ for some smooth rapidly decaying function $f$.

Comment: What do you mean by the product $\hat{\phi}(x_0,t)\dots|\psi\rangle$ in your post? What are the points $x_0,\dots$ meant to be?

Comment: @HenryH Sure, so $\phi(\vec x,t)|\psi\rangle=\phi(x_0,...,x_{D-1},t)|\psi\rangle$ is just one operator (the one at that point) acting on a vector in the Fock space.

Comment: @Charlie So my question is - mathematically - what does it mean to apply all of these infinite number of operators (one for each point in spacetime) to the Fock space? It's not a countable infinity so we can't order them

Comment: @jacob1729 it's mean to represent every point in spacetime (which of course isn't possible since this isn't a countable infinity)

Comment: You mean at the same time? During "canonical quantisation" you associate the field at each point in spacetime to an operator acting on the Fock space. I'm not completely sure what your objection to the number of spacetime points being uncountable is, presumably you have an uncountably infinite number of operators on the Fock space. Although if you want a concrete construction of how quantisation is exactly implemented I don't know. The fully rigorous construction in QFT is fairly elaborate (and often unknown(currently)).

Comment: @HenryH but why are you acting with a product of every point? You typically act with only one operator. A typical expression might be $\int d^4 x f(x) \phi(x,t)|0\rangle$ which invovles a sum over terms that only ever have one $\phi$ in them...

Comment: Ah - so I think the key point here is that the $\hat{\phi}(x_0,t)$ aren't operators - they're something that becomes an operator when you integrate them against a test function across a region of spacetime. Makes sense now!

Comment: See this question and the answer therein https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/584171/157704

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is only one Hibert space.

I like to think of a QFT as just being the ordinary quantum mechnics of a system with many degrees of freedom.  For example consider a bunch of beads of mass $m$ sliding along the $x$ axis so that the $x$ coordinate of the $i$-th bead is $\eta_i$. Adjacent beads   connected by springs with energy $E=k(\eta_{i+1}-\eta_i-a)^2/2$, so the equilibrium separation is $a$.
If there are $N$ masses there are $N$ degrees of freedom.

We quantize this system, as we would any system of $N$  particles, by setting $\pi_i= m\dot \eta_i$ and setting the  commutators to  $[\eta_i, \pi_j]= i\hbar \delta_{ij}$. The   resulting   Hilbert space  is
$$
{\mathcal H}=\bigotimes_{i=1}^N L^2[{\mathbb R}_i]= L^2[\otimes_{i=1}^N {\mathbb R}_i]
$$
where $\eta_i\in {\mathbb R}_i$ is the position of the $i$-th bead. The wavefunctions are therefore $\psi(\eta_1,\ldots \eta_N)$ and the inner product is
$$
\langle\chi|\psi\rangle = \int_{{\mathbb R}^N} \chi^*(\eta_1,\ldots \eta_N)\psi(\eta_1,\ldots \eta_N) d\eta_1\cdots d\eta_N.
$$

The classical-mechanics normal modes labelled by their wavenumber $k$.  As in any "small vibrations" problem   each normal mode  can be regarded as an independent   harmonic oscillator and when we quantize the system these oscillators  are quantized. If the oscillator with frequency $\omega(k)$  is in  its $n$-the excited state the system has $n$ "phonons" of momentum $k$. The phonons are the "elementary particles" of the system and the  quantum fields are the $\eta_i$.

If you make the masses small and $a$ small (and hence $N$ large) so the mass density remains the same, you get a model of a one-dimensional elastic body.  We can relabel   $\eta_i\to\eta(x)$ where $x\equiv  ia$ labels the equilibrium position of the bead and now you have a continuum QFT.